# No me sirve el direccionamiento de <h:Link> de JSF

Tags: html, mvc, netbeans, jsf, xhtml

Estoy trabajando con JSF y Html, migre html a xhtml per la referencia no sirve. La imagen que esta en blanco si sirven por que es html y esta con la etiqueta `a href....>` Pero los de Negro están con la etiqueta `(h:link outcome="/paginas/eventos/List" target="principal">i class="fas fa-window-restore"></i> <span>Eventos</span></h:link>`) no sirven;  utilizada en JSf. Todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde Netbenas.
Web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Agradecería su colaboración.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes compartir tu `web.xml`?

Comment: claro, lo comparto en la misma pregunta